config file with stages in Azure Devops
I am absolutely new to Azure Devops, but was able to create a pipeline with stages. In the config.yml file, is it also possible to indicate separate parameters for each stage?
This is a snippet of the pipeline where it uses a script inside a stage:
- stage: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
dependsOn: Copy_Iflow_to_QA_Package
jobs:
- job: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
  variables:
  - group: development
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: piper-go-official
      path: bin 
    displayName: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
  - script: |
        bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_Iflow1_QA"

And here is the config file:
steps:
  integrationArtifactUpload:
    integrationFlowId: 'Test_Iflow1_QA'
    integrationFlowName: 'Test Iflow1 QA'
    packageId: 'CICD2'

  integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration:
    integrationFlowId: 'Test_Iflow1_QA'
    integrationFlowVersion: 'Active'
    parameterKey: 'LogEnabled'
    parameterValue: 'true'

But what if I wanted to use the script integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration again in a different stage with different parameters?

May i know what's config.yml ? Is it devops main yaml, or template yml? I shared the sample in the reply with each loop below. Or it's the other service yml?

For piper config.xml, to use different parameter value for each stages, you need to use placeholder value in config.xml, and replace it with real value in each stage in devops pipeline. i added the details below, thanks.

If you have piper config.xml content and would like to use different parameters for stages, you need to:

use placeholder as the value in config.xml.
install extension Replace Tokens to your devops organization, then you can use task replacetokens@6 to replace the value for each stage.

The config.xml sample:
steps:
  integrationArtifactUpload:
    integrationFlowId: 'Test_Iflow1_QA'
    integrationFlowName: 'Test Iflow1 QA'
    packageId: 'CICD2'

  integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration:
    integrationFlowId: 'Test_Iflow1_QA'
    integrationFlowVersion: 'Active'
    parameterKey: 'LogEnabled'
    parameterValue: '#{booleanvar}#'   # user placeholder for the value

In the DevOps yaml:
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: stage1
    variables:
    - name: booleanvar                    # define same name as placehold name
      value: true                       # define the real value to replace for stage1
    jobs:
     - job: job1
       steps:
         - task: replacetokens@6
           inputs:
             sources: '**/config.xml'
        
         - script: cat config.xml    # check the config.xml cotent
         
         - task: Cache@2
           inputs:
             key: piper-go-official
             path: bin 
           displayName: Configure_Iflow_in_QA
         - script: |
              bin/piper integrationArtifactUpdateConfiguration --verbose true --apiServiceKey $(CREDENTIALS) --integrationFlowId "Test_Iflow1_QA"
  
  - stage: stage2
    variables:
    - name: booleanvar
      value: false                      # define the real value to replace for stage2
    jobs:
     - job: job2
       steps:
         - task: replacetokens@6
           inputs:
             sources: '**/config.xml'
        
         - script: cat config.xml      # check the config.xml cotent

         # add your code here.


You can add more placeholder in the config.xml if needed. use same named variable in each stage for replacement.


I have edited my question to be more precise

So it's piper config.xml not devops yaml. to use different parameter value for each stages, you need to use placeholder value in config.xml, and replace it with real value in each stage. i edit the reply with details, please check, thanks.
